# Check if view is visible on the screen [Swift 5.1]

Tags: swift, uikit

I have this View Controller that contains the `bigTitle` label (**Please ignore the right-to-left**):

[image]

In this situation, (`bigTitle` **is visible**), I want the top `Navigation Bar` **to not contain any text** (but still be visible!)

[image]

But when the user scrolls down in the `scrollView` and the `bigTitle` is not visible anymore, I want the `Navigation Bar` to contain the text that was in the `bigTitle`, in this case it's *Welcome to our app!*

This is my current code (right now it's not completed and it's in the `viewDidLoad()`) (feel free to change anything you want):

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { (time) in
        // If bigTitle is visible on the screen
        if true {
            self.bigTitle.alpha = 1
            self.navBar.title = "" // navBar is my Navigation Bar reference
        } else {
            self.bigTitle.alpha = 0
            self.navBar.title = self.bigTitle.text
        }
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a timer to track what happens when scrolling; use the scroll view's delegate. As the user scrolls, you are notified in the delegate method. Examine the label's frame; convert it to window coordinates to discover whether it is off the screen.